# Communication between Azure WebApp and WebJob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, webjob

I've created a webapp that creates a WebJob on azure and the webjob returns its progress to the webapp. This is implemented by using SignalR, by following [this](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-from-azure-webjob-with-signalr) link. I can see the progress on localhost but when I upload the webapp, there progress stays at zero, there is no response.

my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ProgressNotificationEndpoint" value="http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Home/ProgressNotification" />
    <!--<add key="ProgressNotificationEndpoint" value="http://localhost:49728/Home/ProgressNotification" />-->
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- The format of the connection string is "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY" -->
    <!-- For local execution, the value can be set either in this config file or through environment variables -->
    <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=inawkwebjobstorage;AccountKey=Z332waP6e4wSeWfm8RPoeG9QwSh5fDxOfQv39dKyGVB513COCbNFRHKcRkq7GBIncJXcDVuASdVDze8D6llyew==;BlobEndpoint=https://inawkwebjobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://inawkwebjobstorage.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://inawkwebjobstorage.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://inawkwebjobstorage.file.core.windows.net/" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=inawkwebjobstorage;AccountKey=Z332waP6e4wSeWfm8RPoeG9QwSh5fDxOfQv39dKyGVB513COCbNFRHKcRkq7GBIncJXcDVuASdVDze8D6llyew==;BlobEndpoint=https://inawkwebjobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://inawkwebjobstorage.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://inawkwebjobstorage.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://inawkwebjobstorage.file.core.windows.net/" />

  </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.2.0.0" newVersion="6.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="inawk.Startup" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="QueueStorageConnectionString" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=..." />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />

    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I hope you've regenerated all the storage keys in this question..

Comment: I've added the keys from azure, just hidden in this question for security purposes.  anyways, if the keys are wrong it is throw an exception while running in localhost but it works perfectly and fails to work on uploading...

Comment: just guessing weather I should add and endpoints to the webapp....?

Comment: your key is there (app.config), regenerate the key for your own security

Comment: ohhhww !!! thank you @AmitApple ! :) done